# When will run “Run <program-name>“ appears in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I coded a Scala program IntelliJ and wanted to run it. But ‘Run ’ option doesn’t appear. Does anyone know why?

Comment: show your code ??

Comment: Look for a green triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it as an object and extend `App`.

For example, create `MyProgram.scala` with this skeleton.

```
object MyProgram extends App {
  #code goes here
}
```

Right-click anywhere in editor and `Run` option with green arrow should be visible. A screenshot attached below if it helps.

[image]